# JQuery Calculation drops cents

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have this block, that pulls the current amount paid on the item from Firebase and the amount being paid at the moment. Then it is supposed to add the two together to make the third variable.

For some reason the code drops the cents off the total.

```
singleRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {

   var a = parseInt(snapshot.val().amounts.paid); // The amount already paid

   var b = parseInt(invoice.payment.amount); // The amount being applied

   var c = a + b;

   console.log(c);
});
```

Let's say the following is happening:

```
a = 0;
b = 10.86;
```

**`The result in this code will be:`**

```
c = 10; // should be 10.86
```

Let's say the following is happening:

```
a = 10.00;
b = 10.86;
```

**`The result in this code will be:`**

```
c = 20; // should be 20.86
```

It doesn't matter what the cents are, it always rounds to get rid of them. I've tried adding `.toFixed('2')` to all of the variables, just a and b, and just c. All result in the same no cent totals.

HOW!? I've been trying to do this for the past few hours, it's probably simple but I can't figure it out. It's driving me nuts! I'm using angularjs and firebase.

Comment: You're calling `parseInt()`, which parses whole numbers only. You'll get better results if you use `parseFloat()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat. But note that JavaScript non-whole numbers are floating point, which is a really imprecise way to track money (you'll end up with rounding errors at some point). You're usually better of tracking the money in cents, since then you always work with whole numbers.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So it would be better to take the user entered amount, and translate it to cents? I want to be sure I do what's best. If that's the case, can you make an answer with an example of doing so. I do appreciate the explanations!

Comment: @Frank, to be precise, if you're simply adding and subtracting, your "at some point" is quite a long way away, involving a *lot* of operations :-) Good to be aware of but unlikely in practice. Non-additive change (multiply, divide, higher order functions) are more problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `parseInt()` is *specifically* for parsing integers so, if you give it `3.14159`, it will give you back `3`.

If you want to parse a floating point value, try `parseFloat()`.

For example, the following code:

```
var a = parseInt("3.141592653589");
var b = parseInt("2.718281828459");
var c = a + b;
alert(c);
var d = parseFloat("3.141592653589");
var e = parseFloat("2.718281828459");
var f = d + e;
alert(f);
```

will give you two different outputs:

```
5
5.859874482047999
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can't parse dollars and cents with `parseInt()`.

And using floats is a bad idea for anything financial/monetary.

Most financial systems simply store prices/dollar values in cents, you can write a function to format it nicely for users if there is a need to display the values.

```
function(cents) {
  cents = +cents; // unary plus converts cents into a string
  return "$" + cents.substring(0, cents.length - 2) + "." + cents.substring(cents.length - 2);
}
```